# Открытие нового окна (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Необходимо открыть новое окно с заданным содержимым (оно уже имеется, наполнение идет по шаблону).

Конкретно - в методе я получаю название окна и необходимо открыть окно с заданным названием и данными внутри окна (данные можно также получить по названию окна).

Код Window:

```
<Window
    ...
    Title="{Binding Path=Tittle}"
    >
<Window.DataContext>
    <vw:TableViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>


<Grid Margin="5">
    <controls:AttendanceTableControl/>
</Grid>
```

и ViewModel (данного окна)

```
public class TableViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    public string Tittle { get; set; }

    public StudentGroup CurrentGroup { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Dates { get; set; }

    public TableViewModel()
    {

    }
...
}
```

В этом методе необходимо произвести открытие окна:

```
void OpenTableForSelectedGroup(object iEvent, string tabbleName)
    {
        if (iEvent is Event)
        {

            // ShowTable(tabbleName);
            // загрузить конкретную группу
            // для конкретной группы отобразить таблицу
        }
    }
```

В зависимости от названия окна мне необходимо загрузить те или иные данные в `Dates` и `CurrentGroup` (ну и `Title` окна установить).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как грамотно организовать таковое, используя MVVM?

Comment: в MVVM юзают пару методов для диалогов: 1) заводят DialogService, который получим вьюмодель умеют открывать ее в диалоге 2) шлют сообщение через messenger, которое получит кто-то кто умеет

Comment: @vitidev, Не могли бы вы подсказать гайд или что-то вроде того, где рассказывается подобное на примере?

Comment: вы рано ушли из чата. Там продолжим

Answer (score 3):

Я бы посоветовал не задавать объект View Model прямо в xaml разметке. Сделайте фабрику, которая будет создавать объект окна и объект View Model или даже 2 раздельные фабрики. А потом уже кодом назначать созданную View Model нужному окну.

В случае ручного создания вы сможете установить все свойства, главное не забыть уведомлять о изменениях свойств. Иначе в этом случае ни один биндинг не подтянет данные. Автоматические свойства не подойдут, если NotificationObject от призм, там есть RaisePropertyChanged, который надо будет в сеттерах и дергать.

Comment: Как быть с коллекцией вложенных VM? Там связь указывается только в разметке.

Comment: @Monk Одно дело прямо указать вьюмодель как контекст, а другое дело ее же через биндинг.